# Reducer not firing

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am standing in a tricky situation.

I my reducer rhythmReducer.js is the following:

```
import {TOGGLE_NOTE_VALUE} from '../constants/actionTypes';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function rhythmReducer(state = initialState.rhythm, action) {
  let newState = objectAssign({}, state);
  console.log("---RhythmReducer");
  console.log(action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_NOTE_VALUE:
    console.log("TOGGLE_NOTE_VALUE");
    return newState;
  default:
    return newState;
  }
}
```

The component using it is RhythmContainer.js:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/rhythmActions';
import {Meter} from './Meter';

export const RhythmContainer = (props) => {
  let rows = [];
  for (let i=0; i < props.rhythm.meters.length; i++) {
    rows.push(<Meter key={i} actions={actions} rhythm=      {props.rhythm.meters[i]}/>);
  }
  const handleClick = () => {
    return props.store.dispatch(actions.toggleNoteValue);
  };
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      This will be a 4/4 rhythm
      {rows}
    </div>
  );
};

RhythmContainer.propTypes = {
  rhythm: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    rhythm: state.rhythm,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
```

)(RhythmContainer);

My action is defined in rhythmActions.js

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';

export function toggleNoteValue() {
  console.log("toggleNoteValue");
  return {type: types.TOGGLE_NOTE_VALUE};
}
```

Even though the reducer runs when the page is initializing I can not get it to run when I click on the div.
toggleNoteValue() is firing up but it never goes in the actual Reducer.
Any help?

PS the full project is here just in case it helps: https://github.com/ichionid/rhythmGeneratorReact/tree/master/src

Comment: You are not connecting the `Note` component with redux.

Comment: Also, you didn't dispatch the action via dispatch().

Comment: I am propagating the function down to the element but I there 3 wrapper components which would render the post unreadable. What do you mean via dispatch @macbem? I have function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
} in my main component

Comment: @PotneySwitters Please provide those parts of the code (the connected component and how it is related to `Note`)

Comment: @OrBjust did so. Still struggling with this...I've wasted so much time for a firing up a simple reducer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple things to try.

- In your project, `configureStore.js` imports a `rootReducer` from
  `"../rootReducer"`, but there's no such module. I'm not sure if this is
  just a commit issue, but it's worth checking.
- The argument to dispatch should be an action. `actions.toggleNoteValue`
  is not an action, it's a function that returns an action. Try
  `props.store.dispatch(actions.toggleNoteValue())` or
  `props.actions.toggleNoteValue()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes notice this problem when reducers don't fire because they've not been put through `mapDispatchToProps` correctly:

```
// WRONG
import { action } from './actions'

// action will still fire as a function, but that's it
const Comp = ({ label }) => <button onClick={() => action()}>{label}<button>

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { action })
```

```
// RIGHT
import { action } from './actions'

// action is sent in as a prop meaning we use the connected version rather than the action directly
const Comp = ({ action, label }) => <button onClick={() => action()}>{label}<button>

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { action })
```